# High score system not updating right

Tags: vb.net

So I have this little game I have for a project for school. Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with.

```
Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    C = C + 1
    Label1.Text = Math.Round(clickey / C, 2)
    Dim score As Double = clickey / C
    score = Math.Round(score, 2)
    Label2.Text = C
    Label3.Text = clickey
    Dim scoreH As Double
    If score > scoreH Then
        scoreH = score
        scoreH = Math.Round(scoreH, 2)
        Label8.Text = scoreH
    End If

End Sub
```

I try to make to so if the current score is greater than the high score, to then change the current score to the highest score (as shown in the if statement). However, no matter what, the label I use to display the high score is always equal the current score, even if the current score is lower than the highest score. =P

Comment: you keep creating a new scoreH when this sub executes, so it'll probably always be `0`, meaning that score will always be higher than it.

Comment: @MarcB That was the issue, thanks!